# Pass custom value to Automapper with UseValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using Automapper in a controller, but the data is not being refreshed after the first call.

```
public class Somethings
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Info1 {get; set;}
    public string Info2  {get; set;}
}

public class Details
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Detail1 {get; set;}
    public string Details2  {get; set;}
    public DateTime LogDate {get; set;}
}   

public class SomethingDetails : Somethings
{
    public string SomethingSpecific {get; set;}
}   

public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    var somethings = await _context.Somethings
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    var details = await _context.Details.OrderByDescending(o => o.LogDate).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdSomething == id);

    var somethingSpecific = details.Detail1;

    SomethingDetails somethingDetails = _mapper.Map<Somethings, SomethingDetails>(somethings, opt => opt.ConfigureMap().ForMember(d => d.SomethingSpecific, a => a.UseValue(somethingSpecific)));

    return View(somethingDetails);
}
```

somethingDetails.SomethingSpecific value doesn't change after the first time Details is called. I saw a couple taking about this issue from previous versions of Automapper, but I thought UseValue was just for that purpose. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong, the config is static. But see [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu If I do it that way, I get a "Unmapped members were found" exception.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Comment: @Diomedes How did you configure mapping profiles? Could you show your mapping profile class(es)?

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo based on your code ,it worked.
Try to change "IdSomething" to "Id" in the following code

```
var details = await _context.Details.OrderByDescending(o => o.LogDate).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdSomething == id);
```